# Different Data In Excel and Excel Reader

Tags: microsoft-excel, java

Due to security reasons I can not share the `.xlsx` file.

I have a excel file, which a cell with data displayed in cell and address bar as `98.3085`.

But when I read it with a `XLSReader` for `Java`, it comes as 98.308499999999996.

Why is this happening?

In cell :

[image: Image 1]

In Address bar :

[image: Image 2]

But while reading the excel file,
It comes as 98.308499999999996.
(sorry this Screenshot could not be provided for security reasons)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28537614/1256347

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664120/java-poi-formulaevaluator-giving-unexpected-floating-point-value